# Getting java.nio.file.InvalidPathException on windows when creating a pattern

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to create pattern using 
Path path = Paths.get("*.txt");

this compiles on using intellij on linux machine but crashes on eclipse on windows machine

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <* > at index 1:
>   /*.log    at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)    at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)    at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)     at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)     at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)  at
>   java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)    at
>   io.equalum.avro.PosGrtest.testInvalidCount(PosGrtest.java:15)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Comment: Do not use c:\ drive in Java. Most of the time you get access denied, unless you have administrator privileges.

Comment: `Paths.get` returns one Path.  It is not a pattern.  You probably wanted [Files.newDirectoryStream(Path, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-).